# Ubuntu: apt-get install apache2 gets apache 2.2.12 instead of 2.2.19

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu

The latest version of apache web server is 2.2.19 but when i try to install apache with

```
apt-get install apache2
```

it installs 2.2.12 which is several years old. Why is this+

Comment: Please post the output of "uname -a".

Comment: Linux B20000-760000 2.6.31-21-server #59-Ubuntu SMP Wed Mar 24 08:26:06 UTC 2010 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The package installed by a specific version of Ubuntu is one that was stable at the time of the release of that version of the OS.  Security fixes are then backported, but other changes are left out to maintain compatibility.

You're running Ubuntu 9.10, which used Apache 2.2.12.  9.10 is no longer supported; consider an upgrade.